# align maths equations

Tags: align

I have this code with multiple equations but idk how to align them to the left side of the screen (each equasion on a different line), this is what it currently looks like. I also use overleaf to compile :) id be super thankful for any type of help, thanks in advance!!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


\[ 1)\ \sin \in [-1,1],  \cos \in [-1,1], \forall \ x  \in R    \]
\[ 2)\ \sin(x+2\pi)=sinx ,\ \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos x,  \forall \ x \in R  \]
\[ \sin (x+2k \pi)=\sin x, \cos (x+2k \pi)=\cos x, \ \forall \ x \in R, \ \forall \ k \in Z
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can many possibilities, like `align`, `align*`, `cases` ... environment for maths equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}


\begin{align}
 &\sin \in [-1,1],  \cos \in [-1,1], \forall \ x  \in R\\
 &\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x, \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos x,  \forall \ x \in R\\
 &\sin (x+2k \pi)=\sin x, \cos (x+2k \pi)=\cos x, \forall \ x \in R, \ \forall \ k \in Z\nonumber
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
 1)&\sin \in [-1,1], \cos \in [-1,1], \forall \ x  \in R\\
 2)&\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x, \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos x,  \forall \ x \in R\\
 &\sin (x+2k \pi)=\sin x, \cos (x+2k \pi)=\cos x, \forall \ x \in R, \ \forall \ k \in Z
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: worked, thank you so much !!